# Getting SuperInterfaces in java

Tags: java, class, interface

I have been trying to do this for quite some time now and can't seem to get the desired output.

What I want to do is have a class name say `java.util.Vector`

get the:

- the directly implemented interfaces if `java.util.Vector`.
- the interfaces directly implemented by the superclasses.
- and, transitively, all superinterfaces of these interfaces.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for java.lang.Class methods? getInterfaces?

Comment: Yes i use getInterfaces(); do i use recursion for this or is there another way?

Comment: I would use recursion. There are a number of samples around, ex http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0125__Reflection/GetSuperInterfaces.htm

Answer (score 4):

You could do a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) using the [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for it.

Start with a `Set<Class<?>>` that contains only `Vector`, and iteratively increase the set with new elements using [`Class.getInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29) and [`Class.getSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29)

Add the just added elements to the `Queue` [which is needed for the BFS run]. Terminate when the queue is empty.

Post processing: iterate the `Set` - and take only objects that are interfaces using [`Class.isInterface()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29)

Should look something like that:

```
Class<?> cl = Vector.class;
Queue<Class<?>> queue = new LinkedList<Class<?>>();
Set<Class<?>> types =new HashSet<Class<?>>();
queue.add(cl);
types.add(cl);
    //BFS:
while (queue.isEmpty() == false) {
    Class<?> curr = queue.poll();
    Class<?>[] supers = curr.getInterfaces();
    for (Class<?> next : supers) {
        if (next != null && types.contains(next) == false) {
            types.add(next);
            queue.add(next);
        }
    }
    Class<?> next = curr.getSuperclass();
    if (next != null && types.contains(next) == false) {
        queue.add(next);
        types.add(next);
    }
}
    //post processing:
for (Class<?> curr : types) { 
    if (curr.isInterface()) System.out.println(curr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although java.util.Vector is not an interface, and thus you cannot extend it with an interface, what you can do is use a library like [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to accommodate these sorts of features.  [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) allows you to scan the classpath and query for a set of conditions like what implements or extends the given class/interface.  Ive used it successfully on a couple projects where I needed to scan for interface implementations and annotated classes.

Here's the explicit link: http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Additionally, if you are looking to just find out what class/interface a class extends/implements you can just use the class reflection api via the class attribute.

Here's some examples:

```
//get all public methods of Vector
Vector.class.getMethods();
//get all methods of the superclass (AbstractList) of Vector
Vector.class.getSuperclass().getMethods();
//get all interfaces implemented by Vector
Vector.class.getInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use another library :  use [apache-commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#getAllInterfaces%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: The link you provided is dead. Please consider deleting the post or updating the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#getAllInterfaces-java.lang.Class-) method from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) will do this:

```java
List<Class<?>> supernterfaces = ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces(java.util.Vector.class);
```